# How parsethrough jsonarray and store each column in textbox

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" `"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.get("JsonCreation.jsp",function(data,status){

      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
  });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<button>Send an HTTP GET request to a page and get the result back</button>
</body>
</html>
```

i am trying to get data from db create jsonarray from resultset and use it to populate text box when a tables row is clicked so far i have displayed the data using alert and i am getting the exact data but i want to access column by column and populate corresponding text

```
<%@page import="org.json.JSONObject"%>

<%@page import="java.lang.Thread.State"%>
<%@page import="org.json.JSONArray "%>
<%@page import="org.json.JSONObject" %>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.io.*,java.sql.*" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%

try{


    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String mySqlUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/permit"; 
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(mySqlUrl ,"root","moodle123");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from enterprisemaster where enterpriseId=1001");
    JSONArray respJson = new JSONArray(); 
    java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    while (rs.next()) { 

        JSONObject obj  = new JSONObject();
        for (int i = 1; i < numColumns + 1; i++) {

            String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
            obj.put(columnName, rs.getString(columnName));

        }
        respJson.put(obj);
    }
    respJson.toString();
    out.println(respJson);
}
catch(Exception e)
{ 
System.out.println(e);  
}
%>
</body>
</html>

the out put from the alert box is this



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/json; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>






        [{"phone":"0471-2318922,0435-6203","fax":"0471-  2315893","website":"www.ksidc.org","enterpriseName":"KERALA STATE INDUSTRIAL DEVELOPMENT    CORPORATION LIMITED","enterpriseId":"1001","factoryAddress":"","isActive":"1","category":"Financial    Services","chairmanName":"Sri.T.K.A.Nair","administrativeDept":"Industries Department","incorporationDate":"21/07/1961","email":"ksidc@vsnl.com","incorporationAct":"Companies Act,1956","mdName":"Sri.Alkesh Kumar Sharma IAS","officeAddress":"T.C.XI/226,Keston    Road,Kowdiar,Thriruvananthapuram-695003","activities":"Providing Promotional and financial assistance for industries in Kerala and acting as nodal/implementing/facilitating agency for mega projects"}]

</body>
</html>
Status:success

    ![alert output its content[1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIlJw.png
```

Comment: Can you post your json response?

Comment: sure wait please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.getJSON("Test.json",function(data){

         $.each(data,function(key,value){
             alert(data[key].activities);
             alert(data[key].enterpriseName); 
             $('input').val(data[key].enterpriseName);
             activities=data[key].activities;
             console.log(value);
         });
     });    


});
```